# FXML keeps telling me there's an empty string

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I had a more complex program but after going over the code multiple times I think I have been able to pin-down the problem, I would love some help checking this code.
This is a very basic version of the other code, but it replicates the errors so I'm hoping if I can fix it in this simplified version I can fix it in the bigger one.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;




    public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

        //SPECIAL CLASSES NEEDED
        public class TemperatureReading {
            private final double[] values;
            private final LocalDateTime timeStamp;

            public TemperatureReading(LocalDateTime timeStamp, double... values) {
                this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
                this.values = new double[values.length];
                System.arraycopy(values, 0, this.values, 0, values.length);
            }

            public TemperatureReading(double... values){
                this(LocalDateTime.now(), values);
            }

            public double getValue(int channel) {
                return values[channel];
            }

            public int getNumberOfChannels() {
                return values.length;
            }

            public LocalDateTime getTimestamp(){
                return timeStamp;
            }

            public boolean noneExceed(double max) {
                return DoubleStream.of(values).allMatch(v -> v <= max);
            }
        }
        //ANOTHER SPECIAL CLASS TO PARSE THE DATA
        public class TemperatureParser {
            public TemperatureReading parse (String text) {
                System.out.println("String received: " + text);
                if (text != null && text.length() > 0) //CHECK THAT THE STRING RECEIVED IS NOT EMPTY AND NOT NULL
                {
                return new TemperatureReading(Stream.of(text.split("\\s")).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray());
                }
                else
                {
                System.out.println("Null reading");
                return null;
                }
            }
        }
        //SIMPLE GUI FXML COMPONENTS
        @FXML
        private Label label;
        @FXML
        private TextArea displayLog;
        @FXML
        private TextField input; //INPUT IS USUALLY NUMBERS EX 24.458  24.435  24.355  24.433  24.511  24.554  24.507  24.515  24.413




        @FXML
        private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("You clicked me!");
            System.out.println(readings.size());
            displayLog.setText("Getting ready to print! Beep Boop!");

                    for (int t = 0; t < readings.size(); t++)
            {
                displayLog.setText("Time: " + readings.get(t).getTimestamp() + " CH1: " + readings.get(t).getValue(0) + " CH2: " + readings.get(t).getValue(1) + " CH3: " + readings.get(t).getValue(2) + " CH4: " + readings.get(t).getValue(3) + " CH5: " + readings.get(t).getValue(4) + " CH6: " + readings.get(t).getValue(5) + " CH7: " + readings.get(t).getValue(6) + " CH8: " + readings.get(t).getValue(7) + " CH9: " + readings.get(t).getValue(8));
            }
        }
        public List<TemperatureReading> readings = new ArrayList<>();
        @FXML
        private void doPass(ActionEvent event)
        {
            TemperatureReading reading;
            TemperatureParser parser = new TemperatureParser();

            reading = parser.parse(input.getText());
            displayLog.appendText("Value Parsed " + input.getText());
            readings.add(reading);
            displayLog.appendText("Value Passed!");
            input.clear();
        }
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            // TODO
        }    

    }
```

I added a comment there so you get an example but in the TextField I place the following string (copy pasted):
24.458  24.435  24.355  24.433  24.511  24.554  24.507  24.515  24.413
2 spaces between each number ("\s")
In theory, from what I understand the element in the TemperatureReading Lists I should get something along this lines:

```
Time: 2017-04-20T15:28:19.118 CH1: 24.024 CH2: 23.961 CH3: 23.889 CH4: 24.163 CH5: 24.085 CH6: 24.107 CH7: 24.017 CH8: 24.042 CH9: 24.473
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
String received: 24.458  24.435  24.355  24.433  24.511  24.554  24.507  24.515  24.413
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$6$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:244)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:545)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.util.stream.DoublePipeline.toArray(DoublePipeline.java:506)
    at trytheclass.FXMLDocumentController$TemperatureParser.parse(FXMLDocumentController.java:67)
    at trytheclass.FXMLDocumentController.doPass(FXMLDocumentController.java:105)
    ... 58 more
```

It says "Caused by empty string" However you can also see that the parser shouldnt run with an empty string (if statement) and regardles before I actually send it I output it in a logfile and it does show the full string as I typed it.

Comment: What's line 67 and 105?

Comment: line 67 checks that the received string is not null and not empty
line 105  is the one that calls out the parser class parsing method

Comment: Is doPass on the textfield?

Comment: doPass is linked to a button, so basically there's a textfield in which I paste the above mentioned numbers, then i click the pass button and it calls doPass

Comment: Is it supposed to be an arraylist?

Comment: your string: "xx.xx\s\sxx.xx". What `split("\\s")` returns: {"xx.xx";"";"xx.xx"} there is a empty string between the two \s.

Comment: One problem is that you are not passing a localdatetime at return new TemperatureReading();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this problem has nothing to do with JavaFX and FXML.

In fact, let's take the streams out of the question for the moment as well.  What do you think the following prints?

```
String text = "24.458  24.435  24.355  24.433  24.511  24.554  24.507  24.515  24.413";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text.split("\\s")));
```

The actual output is this:

```
[24.458, , 24.435, , 24.355, , 24.433, , 24.511, , 24.554, , 24.507, , 24.515, , 24.413]
```

The problem is that you are splitting on a single space but your numbers have two spaces between them.  As a result, between each pair of spaces is an empty string, and that is what you are getting at every other index in your returned array.

The fix is simple: adjust the regexp by adding a `+` to split on any number of spaces rather than just one:

```
String text = "24.458  24.435  24.355  24.433  24.511  24.554  24.507  24.515  24.413";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text.split("\\s+")));
```

This gives me the output

```
[24.458, 24.435, 24.355, 24.433, 24.511, 24.554, 24.507, 24.515, 24.413]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I cant believe I overlooked that.